# Xcode 15.2 Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am getting this error on Xcode 15.2

```
No profile for team '***' matching 'XXX' found: Xcode couldnt find any provisioning profiles matching 'XXX'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcodes dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor.
```

The thing is I am not getting this error when I am doing settings in `Singing & Capabilities`. This error happens only when I try to build the app in Xcode. I have tried both `Automatically manage signing` and without it. I got the same error. I also have attached the image of my Xcode settings.  [image]

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: why `flutter` is tagged here?

Comment: Go to Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts and then click Manage Certificates and see it's showing or not. If not, download again and then try...

Comment: Maybe I am missing settings in the ios folder in Flutter that's why I tagged Flutter @FahimParkar

Comment: Yes, in accounts, I can see that profile